# Invalid grant while get authentication from google only happened some user, but not all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I am trying to use a refresh token to request a new access token

My Code:

```
def google_client
return nil if self.refresh_token.blank?
Google::Apis::ClientOptions.default.application_name = "Qontak Development"
Google::Apis::ClientOptions.default.application_version = "1.0"
Google::Apis::RequestOptions.default.retries = 3

client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  token_credential_uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token',
  client_id: ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"],
  client_secret: ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
  refresh_token: self.refresh_token,
  grant_type: 'refresh_token'
)
client end
```

But i get error like this:
`{"error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request"}`

I was wondering why it happened to some users? and the rest are okay? I have tried several solution including running this command `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` like suggested by someone in https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/84, but still gives me the same errors, any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Add some logging of the Refresh Token, and ideally, the underlying http request. Check that it's a valid looking RT. If it looks OK, get your failing users to revoke access to your app and get a new refresh token for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> {"error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request"}

Normally means that the client id and secrete you are using to refresh the access token.   Was not the one that was use to create the refresh token you are using.    Any chance you have created a new Client id and some of the users are using the old one?

Try and authenticate again get a new refresh token.

Comment: I got bit by this a few weeks about took me 30 minutes to figure out what was going on :/